# Is it possible to view a page in Firefox using "print" media type?

Tags: firefox, printing, css

I'm not talking of the Print Preview - I mean to view the webpage in Firefox "normally", with access to e.g. the F12 Developer Tools, but I want the layout to be the same as if I was printing the page out.

Answer (score 63):

[image: Devtools Screenshot with a nice and friendly ponting arrow]

There is now (June 2019) a nice button in the devtools. See [this discussion](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-media-emulate-print-without-developer-toolbar-gcli/30975/25) mentioned in the answer by @interDist above.

Comment: This solved my problem - the new button was hidden because my style pane was too narrow. Following your screenshot, I widened my pane and got a live print media preview.

Comment: Additional tips for context: this is actually inside `Inspector` tab and its subview `Rules` which is the part that shows the applied CSS rules for currently selected DOM node. The tootip for the button says "Toggle print media simulation for the page". At first I was looking for this in the top toolbar of Web Developer Tools.

Comment: @gaazkam Could you please select this as an answer?

Answer (score 13):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Tools/GCLI : Launch the Developer Toolbar with Shift+F2, then type: `media emulate print`

Somehow it doesn't solve my problem though, this what I see after this command differs from the Print Preview and from what is printed out... :(

Answer (score 11):

As of September 2018, no, there is no such option. The Developer Toolbar, mentioned by @gaazkam, was [removed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1461970) in Firefox 62 in September 2018. There is **no** replacement for the `media emulate` command in DevTools, although it may be given [some priority](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1202711) now that the command line interface is gone. Discussion is also here: https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-to-media-emulate-print-without-developer-toolbar-gcli/30975.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on the existing answer.

Comment: Actually, this is the correct answer for 2018.

Comment: The way I do it, is open the site, go to print, then you can right click on elements and use "Inspect element". Chrome you can do the same. I know it's not what OP originally wanted, but just a work around for now.

Comment: doing it this way @user2924019 there are no css rules shown

Comment: @user2924019 in Chrome, the only thing I can inspect in this way is `<embed id="plugin" type="application/x-google-chrome-pdf" ... />` within a `preview-wrapper` div...

Comment: Reading in 2019? There's an icon top-right in DevTools, looks like a page with one corner folded over. See Alexander Rutz's answer.

Answer (score 8):

This can be done using the developer tools by pressing the 'Toggle print media simulation for the page' button in the styles panel.

[image: Example of print tools]